# iPhone application Picking date from calendar

Tags: iphone

I have searched a lot, but no where i could find answer to my question.

This is simple though. Is there any way to pick date values from calendar. Like textField with small calendar attached.

Then clicking calendar will open it in full mode and after selecting date it fills to textfield.

Please help if anybody knows this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone SDK has no built-in calendar selection component, I'm afraid you'll have to either write your own or use a 3rd party component.

Edit: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634000/calendar-in-iphone-app

Comment: Have you got any idea how can i make my own or any other way? i will really appreciate your advice